# Show that $f(a) + f(b) = f(\frac{a+b}{1+ab})$

Tags: logarithms

If $f(x) = \log(\frac{1-x}{1+x})$, show that $f(a) + f(b) = f(\frac{a+b}{1+ab})$

**Note**: base of log is 10

Comment: Take f(a) + f(b) and apply standard logarithm property for addition. Then do some basic algebra and you will get your result

Comment: FWIW, this is closely related to the addition formula for the hyperbolic tangent, and thence the velocity addition formula of Special Relativity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the most complicated term and simplify

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(\tfrac{a+b}{1+ab}) & =\log{\left(\frac{1-\tfrac{a+b}{1+ab}}{1+\tfrac{a+b}{1+ab}}\right)} = \log{\left(\frac{1+ab-a-b}{1+ab+a+b}\right)} = \log{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\frac{1-b}{1+b}\right)}\\
& =\log{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)}+\log{\left(\frac{1-b}{1+b}\right)}= f(a) + f(b)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

and btw, the base of the logarithm doesn't matter, these properties are true for any base.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it.

$f(a) + f(b) = \log\frac {1-a}{1+a} + \log \frac{1-b}{1+b} = \log(1-a) - \log(1+a) + \log(1-b)- \log (1+b)$.

And $f(\frac {a+b}{1+ab}) = \log \frac {1-\frac {a+b}{1+ab}}{1+\frac {a+b}{1+ab}}=$

$\log \frac {(1+ab) - (a+b)}{(1+ab)+(a+b)}=\log \frac {1+ab-a-b}{1+ab+a+b}=$

$\log \frac {(1-a) +(ab-b)}{(1+a)+ (ab+b)} = \log \frac {(1-a) + b(a-1)}{(1+a) + b(1+a)} = \log \frac {(1-a)- b(1-a)}{(1+a) + b(1+a)} =\log \frac {(1-a)(1-b)}{(1+a)(1+b)}=$

$\log (1-a) + \log(1-b) - \log (1+a) - \log (1+b)$

And they are both the same thing.